# How to return specific info in tuple from Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a simple model with a tuple that is returning info as such below:

```
class Store(models.Model):
STORE_BRAND = (
    ('nike', 'Nike'),
    ('adidas', 'Adidas'),
    ('puma', 'Puma'),
)
online_store = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, choices=STORE_BRAND)

def __str__(self):
    return self.online_store
```

I'm trying to return the store name so I can use it in a conditional statement in a context processor.

```
store_brand = Store.objects.get(online_store='nike')
```

Works fine, returns

```
<Store: nike>
```

Now i'm trying to use it in a conditional statement and it keeps returning false:

```
>>> store_brand == 'nike'
False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well `store_brand` is a `Store` object, not a string. You can check it with `store_brand.online_store == 'nike'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the object to reference an attribute. You should use the correct attribute to refer to the value you want to access.

```
>>> store_brand = Store.objects.get(online_store='nike')

>>> store_brand.online_store == 'nike'  # the attribute online_store
True
>>> store_brand.__str__() == 'nike'  # since you defined __str__ to return the required attribute, you can use this too
True
```